# gwtp dispatchAsync not injected in onBind() method

Tags: gwt-platform, gwtp, gwt-dispatch

I tried to inject DispatchAsync in Presenter class's onBind() method.

```
@Inject
DispatchAsync dispatchAsync;
```

But, its `null` while I try to invoke execute inside `dispatchAsync.onBind()` method.

I need to get details from server while loading.

What can I do for this or can I use this statement in onbind() method or any other place in presenter.

Thanks in Advance,
Bennet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inject it like this

```
private final DispatchAsync dispatchAsync;

@Inject
Presenter(...., DispatchAsync dispatchAsync) {
   super(...);

   this.dispatchAsync = dispatchAsync;
}
```

This way you get the dispatchAsync injected in your presenter.